# mysql selecti inner join and insert

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

Why ? I think thats true but not working

```
INSERT INTO `musteri_order` 
   (`musteri`, 
    `musteri_order`.`user`, 
    `musteri_order`.`support`, 
    `musteri_order`.`order_time`, 
    `musteri_order`.`adet`, 
    `musteri_order`.`adisyon`, 
    `musteri_order`.`adetod`, 
    `musteri_order`.`fiyat_veresiye`) 
select  3, 
        `order`.`user`, 
        `order`.`support`, 
        `order`.`order_time`, 
        `order`.`adet`, 
        `order`.`adisyon`, 
        `order`.`adetod`,
        `support`.`fiyat` 
 from (`order` 
 left join support 
   on(`support`.`support_id`=`order`.`support`)) 
 where `order`.`adisyon`='57'
```

Error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'fiyat' in 'field list'

table support

```
1   support_id  int(11)         
2   support_name    varchar(300)
3   category    int(11)         
4   fiyat   float       
5   printer int(11)
```

Comment: What's to ask? Obviously there's no `fiyat` field in your `support` table.

Comment: you shouldn't need the brackets around this :   (`order` left join support on(`support`.`support_id`=`order`.`support`)) , not sure if that causing your problem.

Comment: but there is fiyat in suport table i think this is true but not working i dont understand

Comment: Incidentally, backticks or no, using reserved words as column/table identifiers is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Use aliases: `SELECT .. FROM order o, support s`. Then prefixes become short and simple: `o.user, o.support, s.fiyat`. Short query, good readability.

Comment: @i486 join is  better than  (from table , table2), isn't it ?

Comment: select  3, 
        `order`.`user`, 
        `order`.`support`, 
        `order`.`order_time`, 
        `order`.`adet`, 
        `order`.`adisyon`, 
        `order`.`adetod`,
        `support`.`fiyat` 
 from (`order` 
 left join support 
   on(`support`.`support_id`=`order`.`support`)) 
 where `order`.`adisyon`='57'

This is run

Comment: Ok, `join` or `from` - in both cases there can be aliases for table names.

Comment: I found problem :)  triger fiyat column is problem